# Hibernate Exception applying ON/WITH condition to LEFT JOIN

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

i want to try to find out all the fieldValue based on fieldName

MNC.java:

```
private Map <String, String>formFields = new HashMap<String, String>();

public void setFieldValue(String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
        if (formFields == null) {
            formFields = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
        formFields.put(fieldName, fieldValue);  

public Map<String, String> getFormFields() {
        return formFields;
    }
    public void setFormFields(Map<String, String> formFields) {
        this.formFields = formFields;

public String getFormField(String fieldName) {
        if ((formFields != null) && (formFields.get(fieldName) != null)) {
            return (String) formFields.get(fieldName);
        } 
        return null;
    }
```

MNC.hbm.xml:

```
<map name="formFields" table="mncformfields" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true">
                    <key column="id"/>
                    <index column="fieldName" type="string"/>
                    <element column="fieldValue" type="string"/>
                </map>
```

here my query:

```
query.append("SELECT users.name,sum(mncfield.fieldValue) as TotalMoney");
            query.append("from MNC as mnc ");
            query.append("left join mnc.formFields as mncfield ");

            query.append("with (mnc.mncID= mncfield.id) and (mnc field.fieldName = 'mapMoney') ");
             query.append("left join mnc.serviceExec as users ");
            query.append("where (mnc.mncID= mncfield.id) ");
            query.append("and mnc.serviceExec.id=users.id ");
            query.append("and (mnc.mncDate between :startDate and :endDate) ");
            query.append("and (mnc.mncGroup.id in (:ugIDs)) ");
            query.append("group by users.name");
```

I get exception:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: with`

If i comment this line:

```
//query.append("with (mnc.mnc ID= mncfield.id) and (mnc field.fieldName = 'mapMoney') ");
```

then I get the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements

If i use `on` instead of `with` I get:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice that you don't have a space at the end of the first line (should be after TotalMoney or before the following from)?